# how to use ${TEST_COUNTS,var="TYPE"} in pipeline email ext content

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I can`t get the numbers of build result(e.g. total, pass) by ${TEST_COUNTS,var="TYPE"}

and email content is

```
emailext 
   subject: "Automation Result: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} - ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}'", 
   body:'''  
      total:${TEST_COUNTS,var="total"},
      pass:${TEST_COUNTS,var="pass"},
      fail:${TEST_COUNTS,var="fail"}
   ''',
   to:'$DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS'
```

I got nothing,it should get the correct number

Comment: Did your jenkins job generate a junit xml report?

Comment: yes, the path is:  target/cucumber-default-reports/cucumber.xml

Comment: Can you show your cucumber.xml in your question,  we need to confirm it's a junit-like xml report, otherwise the Junit Result Parser can't process it.

Comment: thanks again, it works, missing the snippet:  junit '**/cucumber-default-reports/*.xml'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `email-ext` plugin's Token `TEST_COUNTS` dependents on following two things:

1. Your job workspace folder or sub-folder includes junit xml report. (It can be generate during job building or copy from other place)
2. Invoke `Publish Junit test result report` before `Editable email notification` in job Post-build Actions

[image]

**Note:** Remember change the `Test report XMLs` to your value. For example: `target/surefire-reports/*.xml`

If use pipeline as code, should change to

```
junit '<your junit xml report file path>' // example: target/surefire-reports/*.xml

emailext 
   subject: "Automation Result: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} - ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}'", 
   body:'''  
      total:${TEST_COUNTS,var="total"},
      pass:${TEST_COUNTS,var="pass"},
      fail:${TEST_COUNTS,var="fail"}
   ''',
   to:'$DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS'
```